# Changing background colour subject to the value of the Name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been experimenting with a Codepen and I'm looking to change the background color of a span subject to the value of the HTML's Name attribute.

The following [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JOymve?editors=1010) demonstrates where I am so far:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <span id="community" class="card-community-tag" Name="test">Community 1</span>
  <span class="card-community-tag">Community 2</span>
</div>

document.load(function changeBackground() {  
    var communityName = document.getElementById("community");  
    if (communityName.getAttribute("Name") == "test") {
        communityName.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

My end goal is for the JS to check the `name` attribute of a given `<span>` to determine what the `background-color` of that `<span>` should be.

Comment: Move out your code from `document.load` https://codepen.io/koliada/pen/POKVBP?editors=1111

Answer (score 1):

Use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {})` ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded)) instead of `document.load()`:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {  
    var communityName = document.getElementById("community");  
    if (communityName.getAttribute("Name") == "test") {
        communityName.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="card-body">
  <span id="community" class="card-community-tag" Name="test">Community 1</span>
  <span class="card-community-tag">Community 2</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line

```
document.load(function changeBackground() {
```

`load` or `onload` are no longer supported by browsers now change it handle `DOMContentLoaded` event (updated [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LOjqmq?editors=1010))

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using this for your document load listener:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  // Do the business
});
```

so:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {  
  var communityName = document.getElementById("community");  
  if (communityName.getAttribute("Name") == "test") {
    communityName.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to call `load`, but you're looking for `onload`.

```
function changeBackground() {  
  var communityName = document.getElementById("community");  
  if (communityName.getAttribute("Name") == "test") {
    communityName.style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
}

document.onload = changeBackground();
```

Note: Better than change CSS directly in JS is change CSS classname.

```
communityName.className += ' red';
```